# Javascript conditional logic nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

is it possible to do a checker for this scenario

- An infinite loop of number, example 1 2 3 4 is coming into the server.
- However I only want to accept these number once.

Here is what I have done so far. I think i am lacking of one more conditional check.

```
var check = false;

if(check == false)
{
     check = true; // But once check is true the number will never come in
     //For example, this will print 1. but it will not print 2 3 4.
     //If i do not have the checker, it will print 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2.. infinity time.


}
```

---

I have done an additional checker using loops to fix this issue

Comment: With which values you are applying a check ? May be you should deal with `array`

Comment: can you post the complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know about the number of integers coming in a single loop?
if yes, you can try something like this...

```
var counter=0;//outside the loop
var check = false;
var n=4;//no. of integers in single loop

if(check == false)
{  
     counter++;
     if(n==counter){
       check = true; 
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var logOnce = (function() {
  var seen = {};
  return function(value) {
    if (!seen[value]) {
      seen[value] = true;
      console.log(value);
    }
  };
})();

logOnce(1);
// => 1
logOnce(2);
// => 2
logOnce(1);
logOnce(3);
// => 3
logOnce(3);
logOnce(3);
```

Comment: `An infinite loop of number`?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN: Without a clarification, it's impossible to know what is meant by it. But the approach here is general enough.